# ping machine name hits link-local IPv6 instead of public DNS IPv6

Tags: windows-server-2008

Recently (after working fine for years), I cannot locally browse my own web site at http://www.example.com/ which is bound to public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in IIS. The site does work publicly from both IPv4 and IPv6.

I discovered the local machine is resolving WWW.EXAMPLE.COM to a link-local IPv6 address (FE80::xxxx) which is not bound to the web site in IIS.

Further investigation reveals:
(1) NSLOOKUP www.example.com returns the proper IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.
(2) PING www.example.com resolves to the "improper" IPv6 link-local address.

I suddenly realize I may have erred in naming my web server "WWW" since that makes the FQDN machine name the same as the web site (WWW.EXAMPLE.COM). Yet, it has worked previously for years.

**How can I make this machine resolve it's own name to the public IPv6 address available through DNS/NSLOOKUP instead of it's internal link-local IPv6 address?**

***UPDATE:***

Because I suspected a collision/conflict with the FQDN machine name matching the web site, I removed the primary DNS suffix "EXAMPLE.COM" (System Properties/Computer Name) so that the FQDN is now simply "WWW". This appears to have solved more than one issue:

- PING WWW.EXAMPLE.COM resolves to the public DNS IPv6 address (as desired)
- PING WWW resolves to the link-local IPv6 address (seems appropriate)
- NSLOOKUP no longer tries "WWW.EXAMPLE.COM.EXAMPLE.COM" first (double-appended primary suffix) before trying "WWW.EXAMPLE.COM"

Comments invited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the double-appended primary suffix is due to IPV4 Ethernet settings located under "DNS" tab, please check "Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes".

Note: Un-check "Append these DNS Suffixes" under DNS Tab